# adding value to property of an array of objects with a button

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add to the quantity of a product by having a onClick with a button, but when I log the array of objects after clicking the button (multiple times), it is showing `quantity: NaN`.  Is this also the best way to write an onClick that adds values to a property in an object?

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export interface ProductDataItems {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  quantity: number;
}

export const Products= (): JSX.Element => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState<Array<ProductDataItems>>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>(
    "https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=3"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setProduct(response.data);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  const handleAddToCart = (addItem: ProductDataItems) => {
    setProduct((prev) => {
      const isItemInCart = prev.find((item) => item.id === addItem.id);

      if (isItemInCart) {
        return prev.map((item) =>
          item.id === addItem.id
            ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        );
      }
      return [...prev, { ...addItem, quantity: 1 }];
    });
    console.log(product);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Items</h2>
      {product.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id} className="p-2">
          {item.title} @ ${item.price}
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              handleAddToCart(item);
            }}
          >
            Add
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Use the console.log() outside the onClickHandler. The state doens't change automaticaly when you call setState

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
{ ...item, quantity: (+item.quantity) + 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working solution: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-edkkdw?file=Hello.tsx)**

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export interface ProductDataItems {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  quantity: number;
}

const Hello = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState<Array<ProductDataItems>>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>(
    "https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=3"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setProduct(response.data);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  const handleAddToCart = (addItem: ProductDataItems) => {
    let temp = [...product];
    let flag = false;
    for (let item of temp) {
      if (item.id === addItem.id) {
        item.quantity ? (item.quantity += 1) : (item.quantity = 1);
        flag = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!flag) {
      temp.push(addItem);
    }
    setProduct(temp);
    console.log("temp", temp);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Items</h2>
      {product.map(item => (
        <li style={styles.card} key={item.id} className="p-2">
          {item.title} @ ${item.price}
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              console.log(item);
              handleAddToCart(item);
            }}
          >
            Add
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}

      {product.map(item => {
        return (
          <div style={styles.card}>
            Title:{item.title} :
            <div style={{ color: "green" }}>
              {" "}
              Quantity: {item.quantity ? item.quantity : 0}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hello;

const styles = {
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0.2)",
    padding: 5,
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    listStyle: "none"
  }
};
```